# Motorengine (Mongo + Python) : How do I reference a model inside another model?

Tags: python, mongodb, tornado-motor

I have two classes  :

**Projects:**

```
class Projects(Document):
    name = StringField(required=True)
    description = StringField()
    created_by = ReferenceField(Users)
```

**Users:**

```
class Users(Document):
    username = StringField(required=True)
    password = StringField(required=True)
```

I want to reference the User model in the Projects model for the attribute `created_by`. But I get this error :

> InvalidDocumentError("Field '%s' must be valid." % name)
>
> InvalidDocumentError: Field 'created_by' must be valid.

What is wrong here ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Motorengine will raise InvalidDocumentError if reference ObjectId is invalid, so you have to save Users document before you save Projects

```
user = Users(username='user', password='pass')
user.save()

project = Projects(name='project', description='desc', created_by=user)
project.save()
```